# How to reference an element in the UserControl's style from the UserControl's ContextMenu?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

Given a user control incorporating the MVVM pattern containing a context menu and control template, how can an element within the style be referenced from the context menu?  The following code appears to work fine with the exception of the MenuItem CommandParameter.  The binding path of "Template.MyViewBox.Child" clearly doesn't work but demonstrates the intent of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyViewer.Views.IconView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyViewer.ViewModels">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource Locator}" Path="Main" />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<UserControl.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu x:Name="CtContextMenu"
                  DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <MenuItem Header="Print Current View"
                  Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.PrintCurrentViewCmd}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Template.MyViewBox.Child}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.ContextMenu>

<UserControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}" >
                    <Viewbox x:Name="MyViewBox">
                        <ContentControl Name="MyContentControl" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Viewbox>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context-menu is a popup and it is rendered in its own visual tree and not as a child of its parent. To acheive what you need to do you can do something like this

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyViewer.Views.IconView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyViewer.ViewModels" 
         Tag="{Binding Path=Child, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ViewBox}}}">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource Locator}" Path="Main" />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<UserControl.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu x:Name="CtContextMenu"
                  DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <MenuItem Header="Print Current View"
                  Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.PrintCurrentViewCmd}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag,Element=CtContextMenu}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.ContextMenu>

<UserControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}" >
                    <Viewbox x:Name="MyViewBox">
                        <ContentControl Name="MyContentControl" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Viewbox>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
```